# Select same column for different values on a different column

Tags: oracle

I did search the forum before posting this and found some topics which were close to the same issue but I still had questions so am posting it here.

```
EMP_ID  SEQ_NR  NAME
874830  3       JOHN                
874830  4       JOE         
874830  21      MIKE       
874830  22      BILL
874830  23      ROBERT
874830  24      STEVE
874830  25      JERRY
```

My output should look like this.

```
EMP ID SEQ3NAME SEQ4NAME SEQ21NAME SEQ22NAME SEQ23NAME SEQ24NAME SEQ25NAME
874830 JOHN     JOE      MIKE      BILL      ROBERT     STEVE    JERRY

SELECT A.EMP_ID
      ,A.NAME SEQ3NAME 
      ,B.NAME SEQ4NAME 
FROM AC_XXXX_CONTACT A 
INNER JOIN AC_XXXX_CONTACT B ON A.EMP_ID = B.EMP_ID 
WHERE A.SEQ_NR = '03' AND B.SEQ_NR = '04'
AND B.EMP_ID = '874830';
```

The above query helped me get the below results.

```
EMP_ID  SEQ3NAME SEQ4NAME 
874830  JOHN     JOE
```

My question is to get all the fields(i.e till seq nr = 25) should I be joining the table 5 more times.

Is there a better way to get the results ?

I m querying against the Oracle DB

Thanks for your help.

New Requirement

```
New Input

STU-ID SEM    CRS-NBR
12345   1     100
12345   1     110 
12345   2     200 

New Output

stu-id crs1  crs2
12345  100   200
12345  110
```

Comment: Do you have a fixed list of possible SEQ_NR values, which are all known beforehand? If not, what you want is not possible in plain SQL; you need "dynamic SQL" which essentially means you need to read the table in one query, whose output is the text of a new query that will generate your desired output. The problem is that an SQL query must know ahead of time the number and names (and data types) of all the columns included in the output.

Comment: Yes,SEQ_NR would only have the above values.

Comment: What Oracle version? You need pivoting, and the simplest solution depends on your Oracle version. No joins are needed in any version though.

Answer (score 3):

Not tested since you didn't provide test data (from table `AC_XXXX`):
(using Oracle 11 PIVOT clause)

```
select *
from   ( select emp_id, seq_nr, name
         from   ac_xxxx
         where  emp_id = '874830' )
pivot ( max(name) for seq_nr in (3 as seq3name, 4 as seq4name, 21 as seq21name,
                      22 as seq22name, 23 as seq23name, 24 as seq24name, 25 as seq25name)
      )
;
```

For Oracle 10 or earlier, pivoting was done "by hand", like so:

```
select max(emp_id) as emp_id,               --  Corrected based on comment from OP
       max(case when seq_nr = 3 then name end) as seq3name,
       max(case when seq_nr = 4 then name end) as seq4name,
    --   etc. (similar expressions for the other seq_nr)
from   ac_xxxx
where  emp_id = '874830'
;
```

Or, `emp_id` doesn't need to be within `max()` if we add `group by emp_id` - which then will work even without the WHERE clause, for a different but related question.

Comment: Thanks mathguy. It worked.

I upvoted the answer but it said my vote was recorded but since my reputation is less than 15,the publicly displayed post score isn't changed.

Comment: @Cyber_Knight -  No worries, I really don't care about reputation and I believe places like SO may even be better without "reputations" (but others disagree).

Comment: Hello,Can you please also give me a solution without using pivot ?

Comment: The solution is pivoting regardless, but the "PIVOT" operator didn't exist in Oracle 10 and earlier. I will add to my answer to show how it was done before Oracle 11.

Comment: @mathguy..Thank you so much.It worked but I had to use GROUP BY EMP_ID as I was ORA-00937:not a single-group group function

Comment: ... because your problem was different from what you posted? You posted `where emp_id = '874830'` - if you needed it for all employees, you should have said so. The PIVOT solution works just as well; you don't need to add "group by" to that solution since it is implied in the PIVOT operation.

Comment: mathguy,
first of all I want to thank you for your help and I got what I needed.But I would like to point out that even with where emp_id = '874830',I would have to use GROUP BY since I think we are using the aggregate function MAX.

Comment: You are right. What was missing from my solution (which had to be fixed even with a single emp_id) is the FIRST item in select: it should be `max(emp_id)`.  Or else use GROUP BY as you said. My mistake! I just edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: mathguy,Suppose I have an another row for SEQ_NR 3 and SEQ_NR 4 and no rows for rest of the Seq NRs ..Is there a way the results without using aggregate function ? The output should look like the above output and then should include this new row with values for SEQ3NAME and SEQ4NAME and null for seq21name,seq22name,seq23name,seq24name and eq25name.

Comment: Then add to the list in the PIVOT clause, where is says "for seq_nr in (...)" - add after `25 as seq25name`. You can do this if you have one more row - but it will become harder and harder to maintain if the rows may change over time (add, delete, or change/update). If that's the case you will end up needing dynamic SQL, or perhaps changing the approach: the pivoting should be done, in almost all cases, in your reporting software, not in the database itself.

Comment: no,I dont have a new seq nr..The input has a same seqnr repeated again and using the aggregate function eliminates the  seqnr and gets only one row..

Comment: ?? And then what should be shown in the table? Perhaps both names, separated by comma? In that case, instead of `max(name)` in the PIVOT clause, you can use `listagg(name, ',') within group (order by name)` to get a comma-separated list, sorted alphabetically by name. Or you can use ', ' to have a space after each comma; and you can order by other criteria as needed.

Comment: The output should have two rows  of data (if there are two seqnr = 3)..

Comment: Then how do you decide, for the same seqnr, which value (JOHN or BOB, say) goes in which row? And, why are such duplicates even possible in the data to begin with?

Comment: ok,Thanks Mathguy. I understand that there would be difficulty in deciding which value should go against different seq nrs. This data isn't the same as  the one I'm working now(that was for an another issues with names)..Right now,I have stu_id,semester,course.The concept is same..student can take multiple courses in each semesters..There are two semesters..

Comment: Using the old column names and such, if there is one more column 'semester', you would need to add it to the inner SELECT - then the output will have one row for each pair (emp_id, semester) instead of one row for each emp_id.

Comment: Mathguy,I just edited my original question on how my new data looks and the new output that I m looking for.