# Select same column for different values on a different column and then filter it

Tags: oracle

My question is related to this old query of mine.I have an additional requirement and hence this question.

[Select same column for different values on a different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840115/select-same-column-for-different-values-on-a-different-column/39840389?noredirect=1#comment67051135_39840389/)

Below is my table and my requirement is to find seq3name that begins with 'J' and then also select the corresponding SEQ4NAME for the same employee.

```
EMP_ID  SEQ_NR  NAME
874830  3       JOHN                
874830  4       NOE         
874830  21      MIKE       
874830  22      BILL
874830  23      ROBERT
874830  24      STEVE
874830  25      JERRY

SELECT EMP_ID
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQ_NR = 3 THEN NAME END) AS SEQ3NAME
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQ_NR = 4 THEN NAME END) AS SEQ4NAME
FROM   AC_XXXXX
WHERE SEQ_NR = '3' AND NAME LIKE '%J';
```

Desired Output

```
EMP_ID  SEQ3NAME  SEQ4NAME
874830  JOHN      NOE
```

But the issue here I get seq4name as NULL.Can you please advise a solution through which we can get the Seq4name ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're taking the `MAX()` of `NAME`?

Comment: No,I m not taking MAX() of NAME.The link above had more details.But I dont think the link came out well.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you try to find all rows where `name`s first letter is 'J'. If so you need to `NAME LIKE 'J%'` and not vise versa.
Besides you limit rows with `SEQ_NR = 3` it means that no any rows with `SEQ_NR = 4` in result set.

I think, you should use something like:

```
SELECT EMP_ID
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQ_NR = 3 THEN NAME END) AS SEQ3NAME
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQ_NR = 4 THEN NAME END) AS SEQ4NAME
FROM   AC_XXXXX
WHERE SEQ_NR =ANY(3,4) 
 AND NAME LIKE 'J%'
 GROUP BY EMP_ID;
```

**EDIT** another solution

```
SELECT EMP_ID
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQ_NR = 3 AND NAME LIKE 'J%' THEN NAME END) AS SEQ3NAME
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQ_NR = 4 THEN NAME END) AS SEQ4NAME
FROM   AC_XXXXX e
WHERE SEQ_NR =ANY(3,4) 
  AND EXISTS (select null 
               from AC_XXXXX se
              where e.EMP_ID = se.EMP_ID
                AND NAME LIKE 'J%')
 GROUP BY EMP_ID;
```

Comment: @Micheal.Thank you for your response.I just added the desired output to my original query.I need to find the seq3name that begins with 'J' and then also select the corresponding SEQ4NAME for the same employee.I tried your query but was still getting SEQ4NAME as null.

Comment: Its not clear what do you mean as corresponding SEQ4NAME. How rows should be relted? Row with SEQ_NR  = 3 and SEQ_NR = 4? I see the same emp_id but different name. May be you mean that you need to get emp_id and SEQ3NAME only if NAME LIKE 'J%' and null in other case and SEQ4NAME always? or what?

Comment: Yes,they are related by the same emp_ID.The names are dependent names.Seq nr 3 is a dependent and seq nr 4 is a different dependent.I need the employees whose dependent 3 name begin with J and also the corresponding dependent 4 name..Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Add aother solutions where we just check are exists emp_id with `NAME LIKE 'J%'` and if so return SEQ3NAME and SEQ4NAME

Comment: Thanks Michael,it worked.I had to add se.seq_nr = '03' in the sub query and it then worked. I upvoted the answer but it said my vote was recorded but since my reputation is less than 15,the publicly displayed post score isn't changed